# Filtering elements from xml while parsing

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm using the `nodejs` xml parser [sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) to get content from `xml`. The structure of the `xml` is as follows:

```
<item> 
    <title>Some title</title>  
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://example.com</guid>  
</item>  
<item> 
    <title>VIDEO: Some title</title>  
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://example1.com</guid>  
</item>
```

I want all urls under `guid` whose `title` donot start with `VIDEO`.

Currently, it's giving me all the urls.

My code currently is:

```
'use strict';
var sax = require('sax-js');
var request = require('request');

var href = 'http://some-xml-url.xml';

var urls = [];
var isTextPending = false;

var saxStream = sax.createStream(true);
saxStream.on('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});

saxStream.ontext = function (text) {
    if(isTextPending) {
        urls.push(text);
        isTextPending = false;
    }
};
saxStream.on('opentag', function (node) {
    if(node.name === 'guid' && node.attributes.isPermaLink === 'false') {
        isTextPending = true;
    }
});
saxStream.end = function () {
}
request(href).pipe(saxStream);
```

Comment: If you are sure about XML structure, you can use RE to extract the URLs. Otherwise you can [convert the XML into json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser) and then iterate through `item` and check if `item[i].title` don't start with ''VIDEO" then store `item[i].guid` in some array.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to handle more states that just 'isTextPending'.

Here is an example (note that this also handles 'closetag' event to exclude text between tags from the processing).

```
'use strict';
var sax = require('sax-js');
var request = require('request');

var href = 'http://some-xml-url.xml';

var urls = [];
var tagName = undefined;
var isValidGuid = false;
var isValidTitle = false;
var guidUrl = undefined;

var saxStream = sax.createStream(true);
saxStream.on('error', function (e) {
    console.error(e);
});

saxStream.ontext = function (text) {
    if (tagName === 'guid' && isValidGuid) {
            guidUrl = text;
    }
    else if (tagName === 'title') {
        isValidTitle = !(text.indexOf('VIDEO') === 0);
    }
    else return;

    if (guidUrl !== undefined && isValidTitle) {
        urls.push(guidUrl);
    }
};
saxStream.on('opentag', function (node) {

    tagName = node.name;
    switch(node.name) {
        case 'guid': 
            isValidGuid = (node.attributes.isPermaLink === 'false');
            break
        case 'item': 
            isValidGuid = false;
            isValidTitle = false;
            guidUrl = undefined;
        break;    

    }
});
saxStream.on('closetag', function (node) {
    tagName = undefined;
});
saxStream.end = function () {
    console.log('Result: '+JSON.stringify(urls));
};
request(href).pipe(saxStream);
```